Colorbar does not show ticks in hexbin plot (KDE style)
I have this codeimport matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FixedLocator, StrMethodFormatter

np.random.seed(42)
x = np.random.rand(100) * 100
y = np.random.rand(100) * 100
z = np.random.rand(100) * 100

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8), dpi=100)

hb = ax.hexbin(x, y, C=z, gridsize=30, cmap="plasma", reduce_C_function=np.mean)

ax.set_xlabel("X Axis")
ax.set_ylabel("Y Axis")
ax.set_title("Hexbin KDE Plot with Colorbar Ticks Issue")

cbar = fig.colorbar(hb, ax=ax, shrink=0.8, aspect=20)
cbar.set_label("Density")

ymin, ymax = y.min(), y.max()
zmin, zmax = z.min(), z.max()

ticklocs = FixedLocator(np.linspace(ymin, ymax, 6))
ticklocs2 = FixedLocator(np.linspace(zmin, zmax, 6))

tickfrmt = StrMethodFormatter("{x:.0f}")
tickfrmt2 = StrMethodFormatter("{x:.0f}")

ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticklocs)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tickfrmt)

cbar.locator = ticklocs2
cbar.formatter = tickfrmt2
cbar.update_ticks()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

But the colorbar does not show the ticks. I have tried adding the text manually using fig.text() but it does not work as well.
How could I display colorbar ticks for the hexbin plot?
Update: currently the output is

And you can see no ticks in colorbar ( I am using Google Colab).

could you be more precise on what you expect? when I run your code I see ticks on the color bar.

@rehaqds I added my output - you can see that no ticks in colorbar.

funny, I have the numbers on the colorbar with your code! but I see that you didn't put all your code, for example yo have a fancy font. Either try with normal font or put in your question all the code about the plot.

ha great spot, many thanks @rehaqds. After removing the font now everything is good.

The ticks didn't appear on the colorbar because of the special font used. Using regular font solved the problem.
